# Tefillin Before Rashi's Time

Tags: tefilin

If we speak of Rashi tefillin and Rabbeinu Tam tefillin, what kind of tefillin did people put on before Rashi's time?

Comment: relevant: http://thegemara.com/the-real-origins-of-the-rashi-rabbenu-tam-tefillin-dispute/

Comment: In truth, the machlokes is much older than Rashi and Rabbeinu Tam. Although the tefillin found at Qumran did not belong to the Perushim, the predecessor of the Sages and modern Judaism, but the Essenes, they still contained scrolls with some in order of Rashi and some of Rabbeinu Tam (and some with the Decalogue inside, but that's a different story). Please see the link that @mbloch provided.

Comment: Why are you stating something and then referencing a link that says it is little more than a persistent urban-legend? @ezra

Comment: Note that there are legends and claims that Moshe advocated for both pairs, etc. etc. Are you interested in evidenceless legends and claims, or do you only want demonstrable answers?

Comment: @mevaqesh - Not everyone enjoys reading long articles about something when the thing they're interested in can easily be outlined in a sentence or two.

Comment: @ezra If you mean that you summarised the article for convenience, it is hardly a convenience if the "summary" states the opposite of the article.